# Translating Predicate Logic to English

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra, logic-translation

- $E(x,y)$: $x$ can eat $y$
- $L(x,y)$: $x$ loves eating $y$
- $D$ is the domain of all dogs
- $S$ is the domain of all snakes

  > Predicate Logic to English: 
  >  
  >                              
  >   $\forall a \in S,\sim \ \bigg[   \exists c \in S,\ a\ \ne  c  \ \wedge E(a,c)\bigg] \iff \forall b \in D, \ L(a,b)$:

> All snakes, a, cannot eat any other snakes , if and only if, all snakes, a, loves eating all dogs.

Any thoughts on if this is accurate and/or a way to condense this statment?

Comment: This may be the weirdest sentence I've ever read.

Comment: "All snakes love eating dogs if and only if for every snake, there's a different snake that it can eat."

Comment: this statement makes me distrust snakes

Answer (score 2):

Start with the part in the square braces:

> There exists a snake $c$ such that $a$ is different from $c$ and $a$ can eat $c$.

Now negate it:

> For all snakes $c$, either $a$ and $c$ are the same, or $a$ cannot eat $c$.

or more plainly,

> $a$ cannot eat any snake that isn't itself

Now, the right-hand side:

> For all dogs $b$, $a$ loves eating $b$.

The statement then asserts that for every snake $a$, either both or neither of the two preceding statements hold, i.e.

> For every snake $a$, $a$ cannot eat any other snake if and only if $a$ loves eating every dog.

Notice the big difference between my 'translation' and yours is that mine applies case by case: for *each* snake $a$ either both or neither are true, but results may differ across snakes.

Comment: "Every snake $a$ cannot eat *any* other snakes if and only if $a$ loves eating *any* dogs."   I use "any" in the universal sense (anything/everything that is another snake, anything/everything that is a dog).  Your translation doesn't mention "all other snakes" or any universally quantified "other snakes".

Comment: But, +1 for essentially the idea.

Comment: that is a fair point, I will modify the answer to indicate *any* other snake. regarding the dogs, I think 'every' might convey the idea better

Comment: I understand the point, but I believe the spirit of the statement is more along the lines: "a" loves eating "any dog whatsoever that it encounters," and not so much "a" loves (only) eating all dogs.

Answer (score 2):

> Not all snakes is the same as some other snake, and that not all snakes can eat some other snake, if and only if, all snakes loves eating all dogs.

*Note:* The scope for the first universal binding (on $a$) seems intended to be the entire biconditional. $~$ This should be parenthesised, because biconditionals have operational precedence over quantification.$$\def\iff{\leftrightarrow}\forall a {\in} S~\color{blue}{\big(}\lnot \big[\exists c {\in} S~ a\neq  c \land E(a,c)\big] \iff \forall b {\in} D~L(a,b)\color{blue}{\big)}$$

As such, say "All/Any snake" *once*, applying it to the entire sentence, rather than using it for each phrase.   Likewise for the negated existential.   When it is written once, say it once.

"Any snake, *cannot eat any other snake* if, and only if, it *loves eating every dog*."

Comment: +1 for correcting the statement's scope of the first universal binding on $a$.